# Snmptrap fails to send traps

Tags: windows, snmp

I'm trying to send an SNMP trap from Windows XP using snmptrap.exe from the Net-SNMP package net-snmp-5.4.2-1.win32. Snmptrap is in the path. This command-line works fine on two boxes, but not from my XP workstation:

```
C:\>snmptrap -v1 -cpublic [manager IP] 1.3.6.1.4.1.19746.2 127.0.0.1 6 13 0 1.3.6.1.4.1.19746.1.6.1.1.1.5 s "IGNORE ME"
```

On the systems where this works, the trap is sent almost immediately and control returns to the prompt within 1-2 seconds. On my XP workstation, I see a long pause (5-10 sec), and no trap is sent. I'm watching the wire with Wireshark and no packets are sent. I can ping the SNMP manager system and see that in Wireshark. I can also netcat to port 162 and send across a dummy packet, and that shows up in Wireshark, so I think I've ruled out causes external to snmptrap. I have tried other similar commands to the above using different OIDs and varbinds, all have the same result (on this system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahem. %path% fail! Windows comes with a binary called snmptrap...Who knew?